# How to marry EntityFramework, Repository, UnitOfWork and Automapper altogether in one MVC application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, automapper, unit-of-work

First I decided to create one Interface called it `IDataAccessLayer` and started putting everything into it: methods like `GetUsers()`, `GetUser(int id)`, `GetOrderByNumber(int number)`, `DeleteOrder(int Id)` etc.

That worked just perfect at first. But then I realized that the concrete implementation of `DataLayer:IDataLayer` is growing to big. I decided to cut it into several partial class files. Still I was feeling that I'm doing something really wrong.

Then I decided to create interfaces for each logical part like `IUsers`, `IOrders`, `IItems` etc. Didn't work, because I was accessing repository through one dependent property injected into controller's constructor. So I couldn't just add another property everytime I need to use different type of dataContext in my controller.

Then after many hours reading through articles about Entity Framework, I finally realized that I have to use **Repository** and **Unit of work** patterns. And still I need to somehow separate POCOs from my ViewModel objects, although almost all the time they'd be sharing similarities. Automapper helps a lot. But now, I'm not sure how to use everything together. Entity Framework, Patterns, Automapper and Dependency injection framework like Ninject.

I don't have clear understanding how to mix that all into one awesome architecture. Can you please show me some nice examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First here is an overall article about n-tier architecture using the Repository and UnitOfWork principles: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP_NET_MVC_WITH_EF.aspx). I have some experience working with EF and the afore mentioned patterns and I found this article of great help.

Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx) as well as [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx) for the MSDN articles on those principles.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You might take a look at [this sample (MVCArch)](https://github.com/fmichellonet/MVCArch) I've written some months ago.
It takes advantages of :

- Entity Framework
- Repository & Unit Of Work patterns
- Automapper
- Ninject
- etc...

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is great! A collection of all the great MVC patterns working together!

Answer (score 2):

Did you go through [these tutorials](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Comment: @Darin These are good tutorials to get an idea but I don't think you should implement those into a real application. I mean look all the repositories are tightly coupled with UnitOfWork class. And every time you add new repository into your system, you are changing you UnitOfWork class as well. isn't it?